# Importing a custom super class with static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, import, static-libraries

I have a static library that I use on a number of different projects and have recently run into a linker error when refactoring it to split a class in two subclasses.

The error is:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_APIServiceManager", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in libAPIServices.a(APIAuthenicationService.o)


      _OBJC_CLASS_$_APIHTTPRequestServiceManager in libAPIServices.a(APIHTTPRequestServiceManager.o)


      objc-class-ref in libAPIServices.a(APIService.o)


      _OBJC_CLASS_$_APIJSONRequestServiceManager in libAPIServices.a(APIJSONRequestServiceManager.o)


      objc-class-ref in libAPIServices.a(APIJSONRequestServiceManager.o)


  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_APIServiceManager", referenced from:


      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_APIHTTPRequestServiceManager in libAPIServices.a(APIHTTPRequestServiceManager.o)


      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_APIJSONRequestServiceManager in libAPIServices.a(APIJSONRequestServiceManager.o)


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

where **APIServiceManager** is the superclass with **APIHTTPRequestServiceManager** and **APIJSONRequestServiceManager** being the subclasses.

In the subclasses I'm importing the super using:

```
#import "APIServiceManager.h"
```

Comment: check in project settings whether static library and classes added properly to project target.

Comment: Everything looks good in the project settings - I've been using this static library for a while now in a range of different projects - the issue has only arisen since I introduced those classes that don't inherit from NSObject but rather from the a custom class defined in the project itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there in the end, it turned out that I was not including the super class in "Compile Sources" section of the library project

Answer (score 0):

Click to your project name in **Xcode (top left corner)** to open project setting than select your **project target** than in main menu select **build phases** and in build phases options goto **link binary with libraries** and add all your static libraries frameworks here.

see screen shot..
[image: see screen shot]

Comment: Everything looks good in the project settings - I've been using this static library for a while now in a range of different projects - the issue has only arisen since I introduced those classes that don't inherit from NSObject but rather from the a custom class defined in the project itself